# How to replace a value anywhere in pandas dataframe based on condition?

Tags: python, pandas

There are so many questions about replacing some rows or columns or particular values, but I haven't found what I am looking for.
Imagine a dataframe like this,

```
          a         b         c         d
a  0.354511  0.416929  0.704512  0.598345
b  0.948605  0.473364  0.154856  0.637639
c  0.250829  0.130928  0.682998  0.056049
d  0.504516  0.880731  0.216192  0.314724
```

And now I would like to replace all values based on a condition with something else (no matter in which column or row they are). Let's say I want to replace all values < 0.5 with `np.nan`.
I have tried several things and nothing worked (i.e. nothing happened, the dataframe remained unchanged).

Example code here:

```
frame = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(4,4),index=['a','b','c','d'], columns=['a','b','c','d'])
print frame
for row,col in enumerate(frame):
    frame.replace(frame.ix[row,col]<0.5,np.nan,inplace=True)
print frame
```

or

```
for row,col in enumerate(frame):
    if frame.ix[row,col]<=0.5:
        M.ix[row,col]=np.nan
print M
```

but in the end,

```
          a         b         c         d
a  0.600701  0.823570  0.159012  0.615898
b  0.234855  0.086080  0.950064  0.982248
c  0.440625  0.960078  0.191975  0.598865
d  0.127866  0.537867  0.434326  0.507635
          a         b         c         d
a  0.600701  0.823570  0.159012  0.615898
b  0.234855  0.086080  0.950064  0.982248
c  0.440625  0.960078  0.191975  0.598865
d  0.127866  0.537867  0.434326  0.507635
```

- they are identical, no NaNs instead of small values. Where is the problem?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The `pandas` methods that do this are [`where`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.where.html) and [`mask`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.mask.html)

***`where` keeps the dataframe values where the condition is `True`***
*The optional second argument is the value to replace with*

```
frame.where(frame < .5, -9)

          a         b         c         d
a  0.354511  0.416929 -9.000000 -9.000000
b -9.000000  0.473364  0.154856 -9.000000
c  0.250829  0.130928 -9.000000  0.056049
d -9.000000 -9.000000  0.216192  0.314724
```

or the sister method

***`mask` keeps the dataframe values where the condition is `False`***
*The optional second argument is the value to replace with*

```
frame.mask(frame < .5, -9)

          a         b         c         d
a -9.000000 -9.000000  0.704512  0.598345
b  0.948605 -9.000000 -9.000000  0.637639
c -9.000000 -9.000000  0.682998 -9.000000
d  0.504516  0.880731 -9.000000 -9.000000
```

***[`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html)***
We can use `numpy` to very similar effect

```
pd.DataFrame(
    np.where(frame < .5, df, -9),
    frame.index, frame.columns)

          a         b         c         d
a  0.354511  0.416929 -9.000000 -9.000000
b -9.000000  0.473364  0.154856 -9.000000
c  0.250829  0.130928 -9.000000  0.056049
d -9.000000 -9.000000  0.216192  0.314724
```

---

***naive time testing***

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Ah, I see. I figured it out. Maybe not the most elegant solution, but it works. Element-wise operations are probably easier with numpy arrays, so I convert the frame to a numpy array, change the stuff and then turn it back into pandas dataframe. THAT simple:

```
frame = np.asarray(frame)
frame[frame<0.5] = np.nan
frame = pd.DataFrame(frame,index=['a','b','c','d'], columns=['a','b','c','d'])
```

This will return the desired output

```
          a         b         c         d
a  0.791982  0.654760  0.854503  0.552131
b  0.545564       NaN  0.966512       NaN
c  0.595927  0.540071  0.938315       NaN
d       NaN  0.844594       NaN       NaN
```

Sorry for spamming to early. But I will keep it here in case somebody has the same problem.